# Permanently reference a piece of data from another in Backbone js

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, backbone.js, mongoose

I'm using Backbone to create a site where users would interact with content (bookmark, star, etc) and I want a way to store the content a user has interacted with in the user data. Simple enough, but I'm looking for info on the best approach here.

I have built a prototype without user accounts (data is loaded into localStorage), so the content itself stores the user interaction right now (in the metadata of that content), but to open this up to more than one user at a time, I want to change it so that once a user saves a piece of content, the ID (or something permanent) of that content gets saved into the user account data instead.

I'm currently using the localStorage adapter and I load the content in on page load, but with Backbone, the ID of the models changes each time. Once I move to a REST db with user accounts, I'm not sure how to save the piece of content the user has interacted with in their account details object and be able to reliably use that in the UI.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great. How are other people solving this? Custom uid? An id from the db?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Ok, answer was updated, Paul. Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Paul, I also recommend you look into Marionettejs, an opinionanted Backbone frmework that's very stable and becoming increasingly popular. It has a very robust messaging system and it does a great job rendering views, especially with collections.

Comment: @Seebiscuit Yes, I've researched it and will likely use it in the future. Is there a feature of Marionette that would help in this situation?

Comment: Yes. For starters, it'll help you layout and manage your views with it's regions capability (see, in particular, `LayoutView`). As your app grows you'll want to look at the Marionette controller which will help you handle routes. (Don't confuse it with the controller in my answer, they have two different functions.) And also, it'll really simplify your life at all levels by providing excellent rendering patterns. I never use Backbone alone, there's a lot of wheel re-inventing that Marionette provides by default.

Comment: @Seebiscuit Sounds like I should learn it sooner rather than later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** in a private conversation with the OP, he explained that he required multiple instances of the site in various devices to display consistent user data for logged in user(i.e. user preferences should be reflected across all devices). To maintain a fresh link between the client and the server, the OP will be using socket.io.

### Overview of a solution

There are essentially three types of data that will be passed around in this scenario. Site content data which will be displayed as individual views. User profile data that servers to identify the user; basically a unique user id (UID). And finally, data reflecting conent that was bookmarked (starred) by the user.

The challenge is to maintain the user selection data fresh in all concurrent sessions for a given user. The idea I'll describe below will explain how to establish a communication link between all three data sources so that the dynamic data, the user selections, can be persisted and refresh immediately. To do this we will use Backbone's event aggregator, and the encapsulation provided by Backbone views and models.

### Databse structure

Reflecting the three groups of data, the database should be designed with three tables: A `User Profile` table, a `Content` table, and a `User Content` lookup table. A schema should look like this,

```
                     User Profile                         Content
       ---------------------------------------   --------------------------
       | UID | Username | First | Last | ... |   | ID | Title| Date | ... |
       ---------------------------------------   --------------------------

                                User Content Lookup 
                                   ------------
                                   | UID | ID | 
                                   ------------
```

### Front-end design

We'll have to set up three types of Backbone objects to handle the data round-robin. A user view to instantiate our user prefrences object. Views for each of the content items to handle event delegation and item rendering. And a Backbone collection object that will act as a controller, with logic to persist and fetch data. To make everyone talk, we'll install an event aggregator with local scope that all these view can subscribe and publish to.

#### The user and content views

The **user view** is a vanilla Backbone view. Graphically it offers nothing more than log-in/log-out, account profile, etc. links. It's also a repository for user profile data, which it stores it its model. What we care about is that it 1. has the user's unique ID, and 2. will instantiate the controller object with that UID.

```
// We set up the user model to initialize the 
// controller when the data has been fetched
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.controller= options.controller; // A reference to the controller is passed
                                         // in before we instantiate the model
    _.bindAll(this, "initializeController"); // Ensures proper context
    this.listenTo(this, "add", this.initializeController);
  },

  initializeController: function () {
    this.controller.fetch({ id: this.get('UID') });
  },
}); 

// We fetch the user data, which, when it comes in, initialized the
// user's ID
var usrModel = new UserModel({ controller: appController });
usrModel.fetch();
```

Each **content** row has its own view. This allows for easy event management when a user interacts with that content item. Each view will send its own ID to the controller along with an event describing the interaction. Conversely, the controller can send the view events alerting it if the user in a separate concurrent session selected or unselected the view.

```
// We wire the star event
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, "checkItem", "uncheckItem", "onClickStar");
  // Listen to items that have changed in a concurrent session
  this.listenTo(App.vent, "new:item:selected", this.checkItem);
  this.listenTo(App.vent, "new:item:unselected", this.uncheckItem);
},

events: {
  "click .star": "onClickStar"
},

onClickStar: function () {
  // we check if the star has been checked or unchecked
  // Here you can roll your own, depending on your implementation (e.g. checkbox)
  if (checked)
   App.vent.trigger("item:selected", this.model.get('ID'));
  else
   App.vent.trigger("item:unselected", this.model.get('ID'));
},

checkItem: function (id) {
  if (this.model.get('ID') == id)
    // find the check item and check it (without using click)
},

uncheckItem: function (id) {
  if (this.model.get('ID') == id)
    // find the check item and uncheck it (without using click)
}
```

The key is to send the ID on the trigger, so the controller, listening for the trigger knows what to `add`/`remove`.

#### The Controller

The **controller** itself is the brains of the operation. Here is were we subscribe to content item changes, and propagate those changes on the back end, where we listen to changes on the backend and publish them to the views. Here, as well, is where we set up the socket.io bindings that interact with the content events.

```
// Let's define the controller collection object
// The controller has to defined AND instantitated BEFORE 
// the user model object, so that it can pass a reference to
// itself to the user model
var Controller = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, "socketIni");
    this.socketIni();
  },

  // We override fetch to pass in the id we need for the fetch route
  fetch: function(options) {
    this.url = "/user/" + options.id + "/content";
    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
  },

  socketIni: function() {
    var socket = io();
    this.listenTo(App.vent, "item:selected", function (id) {
      // When a check is added, socket emits the id and event
      socket.emit('item added', id);
    });
    this.listenTo(App.vent, "item:unselected", function (id) {
      // When a check is removed, socket emits the id and event
      socket.emit('item removed', id);
    });

    // Set up socket to let the content views when something changes in the db
    socket.on('new item selected', function(id) {
      App.vent.trigger('new:item:selected', id);
    });
    socket.on('new item unselected', function(id) {
      App.vent.trigger('new:item:unselected', id);
    });
  },
});

// We instantiate the controller that we passed in to usrModel
// REMEMBER: This must be done BEFORE you construct userModel.
vet appController = new Controller();
```

The code above may not be perfect, but it demonstrates the basic idea of how to keep a host of views fresh in multiple concurrent sessions.

Comment: But does this not lose the power that Backbone provides - I had envisioned storing a nested object with the bookmarked, starred, etc content in the user object (or a second object like you're mentioning) and as I loop through site content, I could compare it (it's id) to this user object and either have 'active' or not states on the action buttons (like a "Bookmark" button, etc). I'd like to be able to use Backbone's strengths in that I could interact with those buttons and have the view (and object data) update live. Does your solution not break the connection between Backbone and the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop through site content, I could compare it (it's id) to this user object?" Are you thinking of bringing your entire `User Preferences` table, for all users,  into the client?

Comment: I'm open to how this solution manifests - but I was mentioning that my first thought was to have a nested object for the user data (the current user), which would be exposed to the client. This would have a list of all content fav'd, etc by this user. As I outputted content in a view, I'd check that model against this object to see if it was fav'd or not and change the HTML. But I'm worried that since the state of the model (content) is stored in a different model (user data), then I lose all of the power Backbone has with the this.model stuff.

Comment: Ok, I totally get you. The short answer is no, you don't lose any of the power Backbone provides. The solution above simply advises you how to structure your `model`, so you can get to the point where a `this.model` exists. It's a way of getting the model you want to use to reference user data.

Comment: What's more, when you work with user data, most often, you'll *want* to ensure that the local data mirrors the back-end data. As your user makes choices, you'll capture that data and you'll want to persist that data. You're not short-circuiting Backbone's manipulation of models by providing the model two way communication to a persistent data store.

Comment: This sounds positive. Just to be clear, with your approach of defining this.url in my model, you're defining the part of the REST API the model comes from (specific to the current user) and everything else remains the same. That is, I can still use this.model.set('foo', 'bar') and it'll save to the right place seamlessly. What I'm not seeing though, is how the global data for the bookmarked content (on fetch) can come from the, say, /content/ url, while the fact that this user has booked marked this can come from the user-specific url you made above. On fetch, it seems to come from 2 places?

Comment: When you say global data, what do you mean? A model with all of the current user's data or a model with every users data? If the former you'd use one URL to fetch the user's data and one URL to persist the data (not necessarily the same). THe URLs are nothing more than a command to your back-end controller specifying what business/data layer rules to implement. If you're fetching data from a specific user, or updating data for a specific user, you'd want to pass in that user's id to the controller. Then the controller would perform the specific fetch/update routine for that user.

Comment: No, sorry, I meant that the model in your example pulls from a URL specific to the user. So, I could put whether or not that user has fav'd the model from that URL, but the piece of content would have other content - title, date, images, content, etc...and that would come from a different place in the db...the /content/ URL for example. So I'm not sure how I fetch the content for the model and also fetch (via that user-specific) url the data about the fav or not.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I think I get your problem. You'll have one view that has two conceptually different forms of user data in it. One for user content, and for user preferences (fav's etc). How do you manage both in one view. Is that the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68190/discussion-between-seebiscuit-and-paul-wright).

Comment: @PaulWright See the updated answer. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you for this - looks like a solid approach and enough detail to guide me through it. Thanks again for your time